# Grails verify email re-enter

Tags: validation, grails, gsp

I have a domain class for user registration. During the registration, user needs to enter email twice, and those two needs to match. I do not want to store re-entered email and just want to use that for verification. Any suggestion?

My domain class looks like:

```
class MyUser{

    String name
    String email
    Integer telephone
 }
```

and my view looks like:

```
<label for="reEmail" id="reEmail">
<g:message code="myUser.reEnter.label" default="Re-enter Email:" id="reEnter"/></label>
<g:textField name="reEmail"/>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good way to handle this is to use a [transient](http://grails.org/doc/2.0.x/ref/Domain%20Classes/transients.html) field in your class.

Like so....

```
class MyUser{

    static constraints = {
      email (email: true, blank: false) //<-- just a good idea ;)
    }

    String name
    String email
    Integer telephone
    String emailAgain
    static transients = ['emailAgain'] //<-- won't be stored in the database

 }
```

Then, in you view you can deal with the field just like any other...

```
<g:textField name="email" />
<g:textField name="emailAgain" />
```

Then just validate it in your controller...

```
def save = {
   def myUser = new MyUser(params);
   if (myUser.email.equals(myUser.emailAgain)){ //<-- maybe make a helper method in the domain class (myUser.doesEmailMatchEmailAgain() ?)
     // do stuff
   }else{
     //handle error, tell user their email's don't match
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. but what if I don't want to define "emailAgain" in my domain class? would there be any way to handle this using something like jQuery?

Comment: Sure, you could do it in JQuery, in fact there are several ways to handle this.  This is just one suggestion that fits well with 'standard' grails.  Just be careful of putting too much business logic in view.  The view should be for viewing.

Comment: like @MichaelJ.Lee mentiond, there are several ways to do it.One thing you can do is handle the form submission on the client. Before you make the server side call, you can compare the two emails and if they match show an alert. Other way would be to handle this would be to handle an focusout event on the second email and then fire jQuery code to compare the two emails. Hope this helps

Comment: Also, a trasient allows you to do validation from the server side, in case the js gets broken or disabled.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up using this solution. :)

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use a **[Command Objects](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#commandObjects)**. They give you the benefit of having your form post come back as a single object which can have constraints and custom validation (just like a domain class). Then once you are happy with the User's input you can update your domain object with the values form the command object.

Command Objects are very useful when you have a type of form which is submitted in a few places (think User registration and updating User details being an example where 2 forms are similar so you could reuse a Command Object). Or when you have forms on your page which update multiple domain objects or the form just doesn't map very well 1:1 to the domain object.

Not sure how well I've explained that but they're good to know about. Although they may be overkill in your use case.

This page has an example taking a password twice and comparing it: http://www.intelligrape.com/blog/2009/05/26/command-objects/

Answer (score 0):

I have done this a couple of different times. The first was doing the validation in a controller but I cleaned that up and ended doing the email validation in jquery on the client side.

This way you dont have to do the full trip around and back for an email that doesn't match.

Here is a sample javascript function to check if a email is valid. Now all you have to do is verify it agains the first one entered.

You just need another field parameter in your form for the second email.

```
// simple function to check if a email is of a valid email type
function IsEmail(email) {
  var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-\+])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
  return regex.test(email);
}

// method to check if email and confermation email is the same.

 $("#signupForm").validate({
rules: {
                ...snip... 
    email1: {
        required: true,
        minlength: 5
    },
    email2: {
        required: true,
        minlength: 5,
        equalTo: "#email1"
    },
               ...snip...
},
messages: {
    ...snip...
    email: {
        required: "Please provide a email",
        minlength: "Your email must be at least 5 characters long"
    },
    email2: {
        required: "Please provide a confermation email",
        minlength: "Your confermation email must be at least 5 characters long",
        equalTo: "Please enter the same email as above"
    },
    ...snip...
}
```

});

Comment: Thanks, but I think this is for validating email format. I need to check if two emails typed in my user matches each other.

Answer (score 0):

If email-confirmation is the case, I think you can forget about it completely at the server side. It never stops malicious attackers, so as you say, it isn't worth a place in your domain class. Re-entering only help mistaken users, so I think doing it by javascript at client side is good enough.

By that way, I think you can simply use a solution like [jQuery validation plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation). Nothing grails-specific, I'm afraid.

You can also find a [working demo](http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/) here.